# Struggling to understand MVVM architecture

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm trying to learn MVVM and WPF and I'm using the MVVM Light Toolkit. Here's what I'm not fully understanding and maybe it's due to an incorrect architecture of my UI.

What I'm trying to accomplish is pretty simple actually. This is a utility application by the way. I want a window that serves as the 'controller' so-to-say that has a set of buttons. Each button should change the content of a frame.  Example: one button loads a 'screen' ( or a 'view' if you will ) that allows the user to configure an 'Agency' which is a custom object. Another button loads a list of Users from the Agency that was in the first 'screen'. This 'Users' view needs to also be loaded in the same frame. In fact, as of right now, the window with all the buttons really is only responsible for loading the 'screens' in the frame. The meat of the application will be within all the separate 'screens'

What I am not understanding is 1) how to let each screen/view know about each other since one is dependent upon the other. It seems that in MVVM the ViewModel shouldn't know about anything. But in my case, I need to pass information around ( such as my Agency ).

If I can get some hints on what I need to look into, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Some ideas that might connect some of the dots:

- You'll most likely have one viewmodel per view ("screen").
- Each viewmodel will contain all of the logic for its corresponding view
- Viewmodels can and will know about the models (Agency, Users)
- Viewmodels can communicate with each other via the Messenger in MVVM Light
- Think of MVVM Light's Messenger as an "application-wide eventing system". When you send a message out from one view model, any other view model can be listening for that message/event and react to it as needed.

Does that help at all? Keep your thoughts coming and I'll keep commenting and I'm sure the community will as well :)

Comment: That helps a whole lot :) I think I now understand the link between the ViewModels. I suppose in order for the main app window to be able to switch views in the frame, it needs a variable that is controlled from its ViewModel and updated according to the buttons pressed. Correct me if I'm barking up the wrong tree with that one. Or better yet, bind the frame content to a property in the ViewModel..I think I'm getting the gist of MVVM lol

Answer (score 4):

Few things:

- each of your screens, should be separate view (eg. user control or new window - I suppose you've done that already)
- every part of model (eg. Agency, User) you want to display in your application, should be wrapped with its dedicated view model
- your views don't really need to know about each other; you can use commands or events on view models to get rid of those dependencies
- view model only needs to know about **one** thing: model it's building on
- it's good to think about view as really simple class, with one single responsibility of rendering content; no logic, no code behind (unless it's purely UI/display related) is something to follow

You can try to prepare your models first (if you haven't done that already), then make view models for them (thinking what properties of models you want to expose to views) and once that's ready, build your views basing on view models. Other way around is also viable option - pick whichever feels more natural to you.

One more thing: since you mentioned you can display several screens in one (I assume) main area, think about equipping your view models with something along the lines of `bool IsCurrentlyActive` property. This way, you can easily show/hide views with button clicks and still utilize binding mechanism.

Comment: Great outline there. I didn't consider having an 'isactive' property. Excellent.

Answer (score 2):

They shouldn't know about each other.  That is what the Messenger is for controllers and views subscribe to the events they are interested in.  That way they don't need to know or care where they event originated.

Hmm Kendrick is faster.  What he said.

Also it sounds like you kind of want an Outlook type interface, some navigation that loads other views. I had the same question a while ago.  [How to do Regions in WPF without Prism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284804/how-to-do-regions-in-wpf-without-prism)

Comment: Yeah. Sorta like Outlook. In fact, that gives me a nice UI design idea lol. I'm looking at your question right now. Thanks ;)

Comment: I might even have code that accomplished this.  I'm not sure if I kept it.  I'd have to look.

Comment: That would be great. I found myself slowly using older patterns while I was playing around with this last night. It's certainly a shift in thought while using an unfamiliar pattern :/

Comment: Course not I probably won't be able to find it, or find out I didn't save it.  For any bigger app MVVM was more towards the presentation side for us.  A model in MVVM didn't necessarily mean a model that represented a table.  We still had a controller that would wire up all the VM's and what not.  Hard to explain. Most demo's of MVVM are trivial and not real world.

Comment: Sorry I do not have the code.  It was not too complicated, pretty much what the answer said in my linked post.

Answer (score 1):

To better understand the MVVM pattern look at this article: [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Also I advice you to look at [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) framework.

Comment: Caliburn is simply another toolkit like MVVM Light right? I'd be interested in learning all the lighter-weight ones that I can :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Caliburn.Micro consists of one ~75k assembly that builds for WPF4, SL4 and WP7.